# Conditional rewrite in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I want to achieve a conditional rewrite in nginx, such that the redirection occurs only if the URL path follows some rule.

in one of my nginx configs: I have the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.domain.fr dev-web.domain.fr dev.dm.li;

  if ($host = 'dev.dm.li') {
      rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://dev-web.domain.fr/$1 permanent;
  }

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://ip:3001;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

}
```

I want to make sure that the rewrite from dev.dm.li to dev-web.domain.fr does not occur if the path starts with "/scan". In this case, I want a proxy pass, such that my application on port 3001 is rendered on the dev.dm.li domain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a separate `server` block and get rid of the `if` block.

For example:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.domain.fr dev-web.domain.fr;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://ip:3001;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dev.dm.li;

  location / {
      return 301 http://dev-web.domain.fr$request_uri;
  }

  location /scan {
      proxy_pass http://ip:3001;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }    
}
```